# Is it good impression to put ads on a professional blog?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, blog

I have been writing my professional blog for 1.5 years where I am sharing articles on Microsoft technologies and monetizing ads on it. I am following too many expert's blogs and I see, no one monetizing ads on their blogs.

So Recently few questions have raised in my mind,

1. Is monetizing ads on your professional blog is create a bad
   impression in your reader's mind?
2. Is it look like I am writing my professional blog not for sharing my
   experience but for making money?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're going to find opinions supporting both sides on this situation. One group will say that it is unprofessional because all you're trying to do is lure people in with second-hand information in the off chance they *might* click one of your ads and earn you revenue. The other side will say it's your blog, do with it what you will. Personally, I'm in the middle. If the ads are unobtrusive and the content is well-presented then go for it. I might even click on an ad if it's relevant. If the ads take over the blog and make getting the information more troublesome than it's worth then I'll ignore it, especially if the content is just a repeat of the week's top headlines for that category. In the end, make your choice and live with it.

Answer (score 1):

I find it interesting that you have to ask. If you go to a newspaper website, it's COVERED with ads and it is viewed as *professional*. That's why I nearly never go there. Even with AdBlock, it is dead slow to load and 99% of their ads are totally irrelevant to me.

Now, I also have a blog where I write about technical stuff I figure out and I have ONE AdSense on the page. I don't see that as a problem. What I really don't like is when a website takes 10 minutes to load a page because of the ads and then the content is spread out on 10 pages (10 pages x 10 minutes to load one article, no way I'll read that.)

Where I would NOT put any ads is on my company's website. There I really think that it would be stupid. That is, I will put information about my products and services, but no ads such as AdSense or those you pay may $200/mo. and I put your ad in the top-right corner... (which are often much more profitable, if you have enough monthly hits.)